# How do I make permutations with recursion from various amount of input to work in Python?

Tags: python, function, recursion, permutation

I'm almost close to finishing the program but I am having a problem to where if I have more than 2 items inputted into a list like 3 items or 4 items it will only generate output to 2 items in each line until permutation is done. I want it to output in corresponding to the amount of inputted item for each line until permutation is done.

(I'm not able to embed an image yet. Here's an example of what it is doing in the image below this.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9P5U.jpg

```
def all_permutations(permList, nameList):

    if len(permList) == 2 or len(permList) == 3 or len(permList) == 4:
        for i in range(len(permList)):
            print(permList[i], end=" ")
        print()

    else:
        for indx, itm in enumerate(nameList):
            permList.append(itm)
            nameList.pop(indx)
            all_permutations(permList, nameList)
            nameList.insert(indx, itm)
            permList.pop()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    nameList = input().split(' ')
    permList = []
    all_permutations(permList, nameList)
```

Comment: Of course it does.  Because of `if len(permList) == 2 or len(permList) == 3 or len(permList) == 4`, your function will never go past 2 items.  You're going to need to tell `all_permutations` how many names there are so it knows when to stop.

Comment: Which is in the else statement that needs to be worked on? Because I'm using this program inside a program that tests my written program with two names or three names or four names all together. I also tried it without a loop in the if statement and got rid of permList == 2 and tried it with permList  == 3 then it spits out 3 items instead.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am lost, I tried to get to change from `enumerate(nameList)` into `range(len(nameList))` and it gives me an unpack error so I don't think it's that. When I do `print(len(nameList))` after `nameList = input().split()` under if name == main it corresponds to how many names there are which I thought enumerate does that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here; I've only changed 3 or 4 lines, and this works:

```
def all_permutations(n, permList, nameList):

    if len(permList) == n:
        for i in range(len(permList)):
            print(permList[i], end=" ")
        print()

    else:
        for indx, itm in enumerate(nameList):
            permList.append(itm)
            nameList.pop(indx)
            all_permutations(n, permList, nameList)
            nameList.insert(indx, itm)
            permList.pop()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    nameList = input().split(' ')
    permList = []
    all_permutations(len(nameList), permList, nameList)
```

A better way to do the loop is:

```
    if len(permList) == n:
        print(' '.join(permList))
```